# onclick not executing with keyboard even when tabindex is applied

Tags: javascript

Here is my question. I am trying to make the below code keyboard accessible. When I insert the tabindex=0 in the

```
    if (role.can("deleteFilters"))
    {
      w.print("<span role=\"toolbar\" aria-label=\"Remove Filter\" class=\"employeeName\" title=\"Remove filter\" style=\"text-align: right;\" onclick=\"javascript:removeFilter('"+filterID+"');\">");
      w.print("<img src=\"icon-link-delete-dark.gif\" alt=\"delete icon\" width=\"13\" height=\"13\"/></span>&nbsp;");
    }
```

Comment: The event handlers for keyboard are different from the ones for mouse. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp. You will need to create separate handlers for each event. In this case, to simulate a completed click, use the 'keyup' event.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by replacing span tag with anchor tag.